# php -> mysql_connect -> child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting

Tags: php, apache, crash

I recently have installed a WAMP server (Installing the modules individually):
OS: Windows 7 x32
Apache: httpd-2.2.17-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8o
MySQL: mysql-5.1.50-win32
PHP: php-5.2.17-Win32-VC6-x86

I have configured all, when i run phpinfo() it work's fine, but when i use php_mysql.dll the apache server restart.
For example, i run phpMyAdmin, put the user and pass and when I loging no page is loading.

I see this error on the Apache error log:

```
[Mon Sep 29 14:39:56 2014] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Mon Sep 29 14:39:56 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.2.17 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 29 14:39:56 2014] [notice] Server built: Oct 18 2010 01:58:12
[Mon Sep 29 14:39:56 2014] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3988
[Mon Sep 29 14:39:56 2014] [notice] Child 3988: Child process is running
[Mon Sep 29 14:39:56 2014] [notice] Child 3988: Acquired the start mutex.
[Mon Sep 29 14:39:56 2014] [notice] Child 3988: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Sep 29 14:39:56 2014] [notice] Child 3988: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

And this in the windows event:

```
Nombre de la aplicación con errores: httpd.exe, versión: 2.2.17.0, marca de tiempo: 0x4cbbe9e8
Nombre del módulo con errores: php5ts.dll, versión: 5.2.17.17, marca de tiempo: 0x4d25fb49
Código de excepción: 0xc0000005
Desplazamiento de errores: 0x0000acca
Id. del proceso con errores: 0xe0
Hora de inicio de la aplicación con errores: 0x01cfdbe06167ac65
Ruta de acceso de la aplicación con errores: C:\XXXXXX\SERVER\APACHE\bin\httpd.exe
Ruta de acceso del módulo con errores: C:\XXXXXX\SERVER\PHP\php5ts.dll
Id. del informe: a566f778-47d3-11e4-a945-000c2986f0eb
```

I was searching in google for seven hours and i can't solve the problem. ¿Can anyone help me with this problem?

EDIT:
The problem appear when i do a "mysql_connect", for example, this crashes:

```
<?php

$login_db = "root";

$motdepass_db = "ZB1234";
echo "test de connexion";

$connexion = mysql_connect ("localhost", $login_db, $motdepass_db);
/*echo "apres connexion";
if(!$connexion) {

  echo "Désolé. Connexion au server impossible.";

  exit;

  } else {

    echo "Connexion OK";

  } 
  new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'ZB1234');*/
echo "fin script";
?>
```

Comment: Why oh why are you still using the *mysql* extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem. I copy the "php5apache.dll" and "libmysql.dll" from the PHP to the bin directory of Apache and the problem dissapear.

@Phil, this is because i have to reply an old production server on my local machine.

Thanks to all for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

Researching this same problem right now. It's apparently caused by WampServer itself, not your underlying code. Try upgrading WAMPserver to the latest 32-bit version and your code should run fine.