# apache down aftertry to open Magento admin page

Tags: php, apache, wamp, magento-1.7

I try to open magento admin page but my apache is restart twice and down on second restart.

after try to open magentosite/admin my apache error log show me

> 13:19:23.826733AH00428: Parent: child process exited with status 255
>   -- Restarting.

and start then finish at this line.

> 13:19:27.383539 AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

and 3 sec after restart complete apache try to restart again and stop log on this line below

> 13:19:30.097944 AH00428: Parent: child process exited with status 255
>   -- Restarting.

this second restart is not restart apache but apache is down until i go to push start service again.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138269/apache-error-notice-parent-child-process-exited-with-status-3221225477-res

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916372/apache-child-process-exited-with-status-255

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100326/php-mysql-connect-child-process-exited-with-status-255-restarting

Comment: Or http://www.anthonychambers.co.uk/blog/magento-1.7-crashing-apache/7